# How to turn sound effects off

Tags: javascript, function, audio

I have some code that isn't working correctly. I have two radio buttons on a game, one that is sound on the other is sound off.

At the moment the sound off button doesn't turn the sound off when it is selected.

The code I have so far for the sound is:

```
var soundon = 1;
var soundoff = 0;

var soundon = opener.document.getElementById("sound_on");
if(element.checked === true)
{
soundon =1;
}

var soundoff = opener.document.getElementById("sound_off");
if(element.checked === true)
{
soundoff =0;
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable for both the value and the element.

In the IF statements you are using element , while the getElementById stores 
in sound variable.

Change it and let us know

Comment: I have put the new code at the top for you to see. This has now muted the sound on button.

Comment: if sound off is checked, soundoff = 1 not 0.

Comment: I have tried changing it and it still doesn't work. Can you please tell me what the correct code would be so I can then compare it against my code so I can see exactly where ive gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's a better idea to have a listener on the object, like so:

```
var soundon = document.getElementById("sound_on");
soundon.onclick = function(){
    sound = 1;
};
var soundoff = document.getElementById("sound_off");
soundoff.onclick = function(){
    sound = 0;
};
```

It's also important to note that `getElementById()` won't work on objects not loaded yet, so you will want to get the objects after `window.onload`.

Comment: I have changed my code to try yours, it has no muted both sound on and sound off. I have changed it to: var soundon = 1;
var soundoff = 0; at the top and then put your code in underneath.